# How to resolve Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.DataLengthException

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle

The message is

```
attempt to process message to long for cipher
```

and the complete call stack is

```
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.DataLengthException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=attempt to process message to long for cipher
  Source=BouncyCastle.Crypto
  StackTrace:
       at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.BufferedAsymmetricBlockCipher.ProcessBytes(Byte[] input, Int32 inOff, Int32 length)
       at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.BufferedAsymmetricBlockCipher.DoFinal(Byte[] input, Int32 inOff, Int32 length)
       at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.BufferedCipherBase.DoFinal(Byte[] input)
       at MyCode.Bouncy.PublicEncrypt(String value, String pubKey) in c:\MyCode\Helpers\Bouncy.cs:line 80
  InnerException:
```

while trying to encrypt a string of length 360 using the public key, the keylength is 1024 bits

The error seems to suggest there's a limit on the length of the string that can encrypted using this key

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit to the size of message that can be encrypted using an asymmetric cipher. Symmetric ciphers do not have these limits.

You aren't supposed to encrypt messages directly with asymmetric ciphers. You are supposed to use the asymmetric cypher to encrypt a symmetric key (session key or content-encryption key), then use that key to encrypt the message. Then, you transmit the encrypted session key, and the encrypted message.

The recipient will then decrypt the session key using their private key, and use the decrypted session key to decrypt the message.